# SSL C# .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I developed an application in C # (.NET Core version 3.1).

In this application I use MySql via the MySql.Data library (Version 8.0.21)
The application is working fine however sometimes I get this error:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030F): The message or signature supplied for verification has been altered
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.Ssl.StartSSL(Stream& baseStream, Encoding encoding, String connectionString)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

After some research I could see that this is an SSL related issue, however I have tried some solutions but nothing works : /

There is my code to open a connection MySql :

```
  MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=MyIp;database=DB;username=User;password=PWD;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;");
            con.Open();
```

the signature algorithm of our certificate is in **sha256RSA**

We use a Windows Server 2012 R2

If you have an idea to solve this problem, I am interested ;)

thank you in advance

Comment: How long before error occurs?  You may be using a proxy and the timeout for a proxy is 30 seconds.  So if the error takes 30 seconds before it occurs than the proxy timeout is occurring.  Also if the server is off line you will get same error.  The TLS authentication occurs before the HTTP Request is made.  So when server is offline you will get a TLS error and not a HTTP error.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately I will not be able to say how long it takes because the error rarely happens and it is impossible to trigger it on command : /
We are not using a proxy and the server at the time I received the error was not offline.

Comment: Intermittent network errors are hard to isolate. If you are using a Network Credential the Sever that is used to verify the credential could be down.You could be getting errors in transmissions.TCP is the transport layer and will retry, but if the error rate is high you could fail the retires.Router or server may be offline and the connection never completes.Try using a sniffer to monitor the network to determine what actually failed but you are getting the failure very infrequently and may be hard to capture. If you can run a loop to try to get error to occur more frequently may help isolate.